# Using a struct in 2 tableViews (A tabelView within another tabelView)

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

I have an interesting question. I have a two table views, one inside the other. I have a struct that I want to use to add data to my table views. The struct has 2 string items and an array of another struct that has 3 string items. Simple stuff.

The first struct has a  band name, its location and an array of its members.
the second struct had member first name, last name and role.

In the first table view I want to pass the bands name in the label.
In the second table view I want to pass all the members in each row.

I have no problem with the first table view, but I am completely lost when it comes to the second one.

I welcome all help. Cheers.
Jonas

I will add the code below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var band = [Band]()
var members = [Member]()

@IBOutlet weak var firstTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstTableView.delegate = self
    firstTableView.dataSource = self

    addBandsAndMembers()

}

func addBandsAndMembers() {
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Eddie", lastName: "Vedder", role: "Singer"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Stone", lastName: "Gossard", role: "Guitar"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Mike", lastName: "McCready", role: "Guitar"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Jeff", lastName: "Ament", role: "Bass"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Matt", lastName: "Cameron", role: "Drums"))

    band.append(Band(name: "Pearl Jam", place: "Seattle", members: members))

    members.removeAll()

    members.append(Member(firstName: "Andy", lastName: "Wood", role: "Singer"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Stone", lastName: "Gossard", role: "Guitar"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Bruce", lastName: "Fairweather", role: "Guitar"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Jeff", lastName: "Ament", role: "Bass"))
    members.append(Member(firstName: "Greg", lastName: "Gilmore", role: "Drums"))

    band.append(Band(name: "Mother Love Bone", place: "Seattle", members: members))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.tag == 100 {
        return band.count
    }else {
        return band.count    // This is puzzeling me
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView.tag == 100 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! firstTableViewCell
            cell.label.text = band[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! secondTableViewCell
        cell.firstName.text = band[indexPath.row].members[indexPath.row].firstName
        print(band[indexPath.row].members[indexPath.row].firstName)
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView.tag == 100 {
        return 190
    }else {
        return 35
    }
}
}


class firstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var secondTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

func setTableViewDataSourceDelegate <D: UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource> (_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow rom: Int){
    secondTableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    secondTableView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    secondTableView.reloadData()
}
}

class secondTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var role: UILabel!

}

struct Band {
var name: String
var place: String
var members: [Member]
}

struct Member {
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var role: String
}
```

---

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a list of bands. Each row in the table view would be one band. Then with in that row is another table view where each band member can be selected from that table.

Picture is attached.

First Tableview has bands list of bands. Second tableview has list of band members in that band

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of UI you're trying to build, but I strongly advise against nesting UITableViews. You'll quickly get into a mess juggling all the dataSources and delegates. Perhaps you can show us a mockup of your envisioned UI, so we can advise a better solution.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the simulator. I hope that helps. Would you rather have different type of cells with in just one tableView?

Comment: If you only have a fix amount of fields that you want to display (3?) in your inner tableviews, why not just create a custom tableViewCell that has enough labels for that? I think you'd make your life easier.

Comment: I had been thinking about that as well. I just could not figure out how I would have the row 1 as the band info and then get x number of rows as cell 2 with members info, then again one row with cell 1 and band info...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what I would do here is use sections. Each band get its own table view section, and each row within that section is a band member. The section header can contain a label for the band name, and each row can have a label for the member.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return bands.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    return bands[section].members.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return bands[section].name
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! secondTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell here...
    return cell
}
```

Also, I would rename `secondTableViewCell` to `BandMemberCell` to make it clear what it represents.